# Dynamically set proxy for docker pull

Tags: docker, proxy

I'm trying to pull an image from a server with multiple proxies.

Setting a proper proxy depends on which zone the machine is trying to `docker pull` from.

For the record, adding the one relevant proxy in `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.conf/http-proxy.conf` of the machine which is pulling the image, **works fine**.

**But** the container is supposed to be downloaded on multiple zones, which require different proxies based on where the machine is.

I tried two things:

1. Passed the list of proxies in the `http-proxy.conf`, like this:

```
[Service]
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_1:port/,http://proxy_2:port/"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy_1:port/,http://proxy_2:port/"
Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost"
```

Some machines require `http://proxy_1:port/`, which work fine.

But on a machine that requires `http://proxy_2:port/` to pull; it does **not** work, meaning, Docker does not fallback to another proxy to try. It returns this error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get HTTP:<ip>:<proxy_1> proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp <ip>:<proxy_1>: connect: no route to host
```

Ofcourse if I were to provide only the second working proxy to the configuration, it will work.

2. Passing proxy as a parameter to `docker pull`, like in `docker build/run` but that is not supported as per the documentation.

I am looking for a way to set-up proxies in such a way that either

Docker falls back to trying other provided alternate proxies

OR

I can provide proxy dynamically at the time of pull. (This will be part of an automated process which determines relevant proxy to pass.)

I do not want to constantly change the http-proxy file and restart docker for obvious reasons.

What are my options?

Answer (score -2):

If you're using a sufficiently recent docker (i.e. 17.07 and higher) you can have this configuration on the client side. Refer to the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client) for details on the configuration.

You still need to have multiple configuration files for the various proxy configuration you need, but you can switch them without the need to restart the docker daemon.

In order to do something similar (not exactly related to proxy) I use a shell script that wraps the invocation of docker client pointing to a custom configuration file via the `--config` option.

Comment: I guess that config affects the running containers' environment variables. What I am trying to change is the Docker daemon's proxy settings, which I fear this script doesn't do, but the docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf does.